# What is the best way to hide the main form on application's startup

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way to hide the main form on application's startup to show it later?

If I just call the `Hide` method in the `Load` event of this form it gives a terrible flash for some time before actually hiding it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest way is to set `Opacity = 0` in the designer..

Comment: There are lots of answers here that'll probably help you, but I'm just asking this out of curiosity:  Why are you hiding the main form & how long into the running of the application would the main form be displayed?  If it's just due to loading data, then the splash screen method is the best way to go, but I'm just curious of the end-game here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to set `Opacity = 0` in the designer.  Of course you will want to set it back to `100` at some point later..

Or you may want to use a splash screen, maybe like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Splash splash = new Splash();
        splash.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

With a splash screen:

```
public partial class Splash : Form
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form1 form1 = new Form1();

    private void Splash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        form1.Hide();
    }

}
```

You can then show it for example when the splash screen is closed:

```
private void Splash_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    form1.Show();
    form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Which would happen whenever you want or maybe after some time:

```
public Splash()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.Interval = 5000;
  timer.Enabled = true;
  timer.Tick +=  (s,e) =>{ this.Close();};
}
```

Since the program is not watching a Form to close we also need to add this to the main form's closed event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

If you don't want the splash screen to be visible at all you can hide it like this:

```
public Splash()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Opacity = 0;
```

But please make sure you don't leave the users in the blind: When I start a program I want immediate response!!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Program class - this is where the form is created and shown:

```
static class Program {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main () {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Visible = false;
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Hopefully your adding some sort of user interface?

Comment: In this case the `Load` event will never called. How can I catch it to do some stuff?

Comment: it depends what stuff you want to do. I can't see the use for a windows forms app without a form but you know what you're doing...  try setting the windowstate to minimized and the showInTaskbar property to false. Just noticed you accepted an answer that does something else entirely... I'll leave this here anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Settings.Instance.HideAtStartup)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        Hide();
    }));
}
}
```

An alternative way can be to use the [Application.Run(Form)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) method.  You can create the main form with its [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property initially set to **false**, and provide no argument to [Application.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) in main loop.

Comment: If I just call the `Hide` method in the `Load` event of this form it gives a terrible flash for some time before actually hiding it

Comment: @FrozenHeart:- I have added one more alternative method. Check that

Comment: In this case the `Load` event will never called. How can I catch it to do some stuff?